# Extract data from string using python (convert string dictionary to dictionary)

Tags: python, string

I have a string (string dictionary) as below, with key and value pairs. How do I extract the 'text' information out using Python. Extracted_data = xxxxxx

```
data = '{"Created":"Wed", "id":1435,"text":"xxxxxx"}'
print(type(data)) = string
```

Comment: `extracted_data = data['text']`

Comment: import json; json.loads(data).get('text') ?

Comment: Psidom's answer actually works. Thanks

Comment: [Can refer to the link below for more methods, import json or import ast should work equally well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
from json import loads
data = """ 
{"Created":"Wed", "id":1435,"text":"xxxxxx"}
       """
data = loads(data)
text = data["text"]
created = data["Created"]
id = data["id"]
print(id)
print(created)
print(text)
```

Outputs

```
1435
Wed
xxxxxx
```

So basically you are converting the string to the dictionary

Comment: is not a dictionary, the problem here is to convert a string dictionary to a dictionary. Found out that below 2 lines worked import json result = json.loads(string)

Comment: hey i have fixed it so you can use this now

Answer (score 0):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-string-dictionary-to-dictionary/

Here is what is working:

```
import json
  
# initializing string 
test_string = '{"Nikhil" : 1, "Akshat" : 2, "Akash" : 3}' 
  
# printing original string 
print("The original string : " + str(test_string))
  
# using json.loads()
# convert dictionary string to dictionary
res = json.loads(test_string)
```